# How to fetch the text in a tag which contains translate in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, angular6

Here is my html,

```
    <p id="on-board" class="on-board-text">
    {{
      'OVERVIEW.WELCOME_SCREEN_ON_BOARD'
      | translate
       : {
          USER_NAME:
            username
        }
     }}</p>
```

Where,

```
      username = 'banner works!';
```

I am trying to fetch the value of USER_NAME.

Here is my spec,

```
   it('Check if username is populated', async () => {
      const { find } = await shallow.render({});
      const htmlDiv = find('.on-board-text');
      const user = htmlDiv.nativeElement.textContent.trim();
      expect(user).toEqual('banner works!');
   });
```

But here I am getting 'user' in spec as  empty (" ").

Can anyone please suggest me help.Thanks.

Comment: Have you initialised a translation service?

Comment: It looks like https://github.com/ngx-translate/core. consider adding a tag to identify the library as a component of your question.

Comment: Also, if using ngx-translate, consider looking at [this discussion](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/636), especially [this comment](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/636#issuecomment-387332262)

Comment: I tired your suggestion but seems not usefull for my case...